# Laravel validation overwriting my values?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.8 (also tested with Laravel 6.1.0) job that periodically downloads a file from the [NOAA Spacer Weather Prediction Centre](https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/json/rtsw/rtsw_mag_1m.json). As part of the job, I want to validate some of the attributes before inserting them into the database and fail the job if things aren't right.

The SWPC file is a JSON file that contains an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  [{
    time_tag: "2019-10-02T13:39:00",
    bt: 4.45,
    bz_gsm: 0.09,
    // (there are lots of other, irrelevant fields here)
  }, {
    // (more of the same data here, repeated dozens of times)
  }]
```

The main part of my job looks like this:

```php
  $request = $guzzle->request('GET', 'https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/json/rtsw/rtsw_mag_1m.json');
  $imf = collect(json_decode($request->getBody()->__toString()));

  Validator::make($imf->all(), [
    '*.time_tag' => 'required|date', // Must be a valid date
    '*.bt' => 'required', // Bt must be present
    '*.bz_gsm' => 'required', // Bz must be present
  ])->validate();

  dd($imf->first());
```

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#automatic-redirection), calling `validate()` on a manually created Validator should act the same as if you validated a request object (that is: "If validation fails, the user will automatically be redirected or, in the case of an AJAX request, a JSON response will be returned")

However with the above code, validation passes, but the `time_tag`, `bt` and `bz_gsm` fields are null. If I remove the `time_tag` validation rule, `time_tag` is no longer null (but `bt` and `bz_gsm` are null). Same with the `bt` and `bz_gsm` fields. Basically any field that gets validated, is nulled.

If I change my validation code to this:

```php
  $validator = Validator::make($imf->all(), [
    '*.time_tag' => 'required|date', 
    '*.bt' => 'required|file', // Bt is not an uploaded file! Validation should fail.
    '*.bz_gsm' => 'required',
  ]);

  dd($validator->fails());
```

Then `fails` is `false` (i.e., validation passes). If I `dd($imf->first())`, then once again `time_tag`, `bt` and `bz_gsm` are null, while every other element in `$imf` is the original value.

As far as I'm aware, my matches are correct, because `dd($imf->all())` before, gives a lot of output that looks like this:

```php
array:2031 [
  0 => {#922
    +"time_tag": "2019-10-02T23:55:00"
    +"active": true
    +"source": "ACE"
    +"range": null
    +"scale": null
    +"sensitivity": null
    +"manual_mode": false
    +"sample_size": 60
    +"bt": 3.48
    +"bx_gse": -3.13
    +"by_gse": 0.58
    +"bz_gse": 1.4
    +"theta_gse": 23.73
    +"phi_gse": 169.57
    +"bx_gsm": -3.13
    +"by_gsm": 0.9
    +"bz_gsm": 1.23
    +"theta_gsm": 20.65
    +"phi_gsm": 164.0
    +"max_telemetry_flag": 0
    +"max_data_flag": 0
    +"overall_quality": 0
  }
// ... a few thousand more lines of output here
```

while `dd($imf->all())` after validation gives me:

```php
array:2032 [
  0 => {#922
    +"time_tag": null
    +"active": true
    +"source": "ACE"
    +"range": null
    +"scale": null
    +"sensitivity": null
    +"manual_mode": false
    +"sample_size": 60
    +"bt": null
    +"bx_gse": -3.16
    +"by_gse": 0.94
    +"bz_gse": 1.2
    +"theta_gse": 20.01
    +"phi_gse": 163.43
    +"bx_gsm": -3.15
    +"by_gsm": 1.2
    +"bz_gsm": null
    +"theta_gsm": 15.69
    +"phi_gsm": 159.09
    +"max_telemetry_flag": 0
    +"max_data_flag": 0
    +"overall_quality": 0
  }
// ... a few thousand more lines of output here
```

So it's finding the keys it needs, and is just overwriting those while leaving the rest of the info.

Is there some hidden trick to validating arrays of data, or validating data in a Laravel job?

Comment: It looks like the validation isn't finding the keys that you are trying to match up with *.<match>.. can you try dd() with `$imf->all()` let me know what you get?

Comment: @RohitS I've edited my question to add the information. The short answer is, validation seems to be finding the keys okay because it's overwriting just those keys in every element of the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see in your `dd()` that what you're passing to the validator is an array of stdObjects (which is the default for `json_decode()` when it sees `{}`). However, the `'*.blah'` notation for the validator is actually for validating an array of arrays. Apparently, you have discovered that you get strange behavior when passing it objects instead or arrays.

The simple fix is to pass a [second argument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) of `true` to `json_decode()`, which will convert the objects to associative arrays so that the Validator can parse them properly.

```php
$imf = collect(json_decode($request->getBody()->__toString(), true));
```

*Note*: this also changes the structure of `$imf` from what you had; any processing you do with it after validation will have to be appropriately adjusted.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Given that collections are a "fluent, convenient wrapper for working with arrays of data", I guess I expected that Laravel would handle that sort of stuff automatically, or at least throw an error. But it's a lesson learned. Thanks!